# Is it still good practice to use end of a large hard drive as data partition?

Tags: partitioning

Does it make sense

- to use the end of a large hard drive as a data partition?

That was normal for me when I was still using Window. Does that still make sense?

Why not just back up the **home directory**?

Can't the **OS be backed** up and restored from **certain folders**?

Comment: Not clear what your actual question is. If you're asking if there is a difference in transfer speed between the first and last sectors of an HDD, the answer is yes, although I doubt that will make a noticeable difference in real life. For the rest please clarify.

Comment: At times with Windows it was common to save the data on an extra partition (or better, extra hard drive). It was easy to change the partition sizes later, e.g. the operating system needed more space. Years ago the folder names were often too long when creating projects in the home directory. Maybe times have changed. Maybe it's different from the Windows OS.

Comment: I don't know, you seem to switch from one topic to the other. You are free to create a data partition or not on your hard drives. Filename length is usually limited to 255 characters, path length often to 4096. There is plenty of info on that online.